# Cannot boot cd/dvd drive on NEC laptop

Tags: boot

I have a Japanese manufactured laptop (NEC). In the BIOS, I have set the CD drive as the primary boot up device; however, on start up, only the HDD boots. The only key to press at the POST screen is F2 which starts the BIOS. There is not a key to press for a boot device selection. Anyone have any ideas on how I can keep this from starting the HDD only? I would really like to install this other OS..

EDIT: Just tried three different install CD's. Other than the primary CD/DVD drive, I also tried a USB CD/DVD drive as well. Neither worked.

The computer model is: NEC PC-LS550BS6R

Comment: Have you tried pressing F8 at boot? That's like the universal boot menu key, though not always...

Comment: @PeterMaxwell: I tried pressing F12, F8, and DEL

Comment: Could the CD you're trying to boot from be faulty?

Comment: I tried 3 different OS install CD's

Comment: Can you provide the NEC model?

Comment: and you're sure the CD drive works?

Comment: @PeterMaxwell: I tried two different CD drives